# Change the version of excel attached file in email using c#

Tags: c#, excel, email, smtp

I am trying to send the email with attached excel xlsx file.
I can download the attached excel file on my laptop, and galaxy phone but I can't download it on the iphone. 
 So I want to lower the excel version using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx. 
For this, when I change the code to

```
 wb.SaveAs("filename.xls", FileFormat: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8);
```

It says SaveAs does not have a parameter for FileFormat.
They said they need 2 parameters. (Stream stream, bool validate)

So I have no idea where can I put those fileformat to change the fileformat from xlsx to xls on my code.

```
 //set DataTable Name of Excel Sheet
  data.TableName = "E_Data";

//Create a New Workbook
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
//Add the DataTable as Excel Workhseet
wb.Worksheets.Add(data);

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Save the Excel Workbook to MemoryStream
    wb.SaveAs(memoryStream);

    //Convert MemoryStream to Byte array
    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    memoryStream.Close();

     ...


      mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "NSOList.xlsx"));
}
}
```

Comment: do you use `ClosedXml` libary? can you use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace?

Comment: @jonathana Yes I am using ClosedXml, I download "Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel " So I can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ClosedXml` Libary, ClosedXML doesn't support the older format, hence you can not save your file as xls.
if you can use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace (i.e office is installed on server \ pc)  it will be very easy, create your excel file **using Interop.Excel** and than save it
using `SaveAs()` method for example: `wb.SaveAs(c:\\memoryStream.xls,XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)`